# How to Retrive and Store NSArray from sqlite DB in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsarray, nskeyedarchiver

I have an array itemQtyArray which i am storing in SQLITE table As:

```
    NSData *toData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.itemQtyArray];

    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO ORDERTABLE(ITEMDESC,ITEMQTY)VALUES( \"%@\",\"%@\");",dataString2,toData];
```

and then i am retrieving as :

```
    const void *itemQty = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
    NSInteger qtyBytes = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 2);
    NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithBytes:itemQty length:qtyBytes];
    NSArray *myArrayFromDB = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    myArrayFromDB = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data2];
    [self.itemQtyArray addObjectsFromArray:myArrayFromDB];
```

BUt i am getting Exception  at line

```
    myArrayFromDB = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data2];
```

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:

```
    '-[__NSCFData objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Please tell what is wrong

Comment: Can you show what you are storing in itemQtyArray?

Comment: HI anup i am storing integer values only like 2,3 ,5

Answer (score 3):

```
NSData *toData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
```

instead of this you should pass NSDictionary

```
NSData *toData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary];
```

or

o convert a generic array to an NSData, you need an archiver! If you know how to feed the NSData, you know how to use NSKeyedArchiver. So:

```
NSArray* array= ... ;
NSData* data=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
```

Of course all elements in your array needs to implement   [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol

Comment: Thanks Divz, 
but how should i covert array to nsdata , only thing i found here using Archiver  i.e i used that.
can you please explain how should i do that , i have n to much exp in iOS

Comment: @Sulabh i have already mentioned for the array please have a look.

Comment: @Sulabh for more details have a look of http://soff.es/archiving-objective-c-objects-with-nscoding

Comment: Are you using NSArray or NSMutableArray if NSArray then please use NSMutableArray

Comment: i have used NSArray while retrieving , so should i change to nsmutable.

Comment: @Sulabh yes you have to change that

Comment: this Link , demonstates that i have to convert my array to dictionary 
and then to nsdata .
but my Array will be very large sometimes. and it is not possible for encode each Object of my array

Comment: changing myArrayFromDB to nsmutable array have not changed anything , as it is not a problem  i guess. because while retrieving my array will be having fixed value.

Comment: is there any method by which either i can store nsarray to sqlite and retrieved that again directly to array

Comment: You can directly convert it into NSData and ate the time of retrival you can restore the data into the array.

Comment: thats what i want to know how to convert 
i tried using archiving but that doesn't worked.

Comment: @Sulabh If you array contains any custom objects, you need to implement NSCoding protocol, and have to serialize while storing the array into sqlite as data and deserialize back to array. The suggestion of Divz is a valid one. If you are finding it difficult, try using FMDB. They are providing a good wrapper around the native c based sqlite provided by iOS.

Comment: ya i have , checked , actually i  my array is very large ,then it is bit long to encode each object

Comment: thanx @Anupdas i have already trying to help him but i think i didnt get me

Comment: Anup can u please give any example how to implement NSCoding protocol  in my case

Comment: @Sulabh As you are only storing integers in that array, you don't need to implement NSCoding protocol. The link provided by Divz is a very good tutorial. For your query i worked out a sample with FMDB, its working fine.

Comment: thanks Anup , can you please share here how  have ou done it.
and i don't know what is this FMDB

Comment: @Sulabh I reworked another version for you, i have kept the name of the table and two rows same as that of your solution. Here is the [Source Code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/DemoDataSqlite.zip). Let me know your thoughts

Comment: @Anupdas thanks man.
but you have used something FMDatabase , and in which it you have directly used dataForColumn  , and you have unarchived it .
but for my case i am using SQLite3 database . i don't know why its not working here

Comment: @Sulabh This is [tutorial for FMDB](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/836_Persisting_iOS_Application_Data_in_SQLite_Database_Using_FMDB.aspx), give it a try.

Comment: but then i have to change my database right , that will be again overhead .to do so, just for solving one thing