# Save and retrive NSMutableArray in sqlite in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite

I have a `NSMutableArray` of `NSDictionary` which I want to store in sqlite in iOS. I tried:

*in .h*

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *mutArrayOfDict;
```

At sqlite insert:

```
NSData *wrtData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:mutArrayOfDict];
sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 5, wrtData, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

At sqlite read:

```
blob = sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 5);
bytes = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 5);
readData = [NSData dataWithBytes:blob length:bytes];

mutArrayOfDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:readData]; //Exception
```

*Exception*

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive....
```

I tried:

```
[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:readData
                                 mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                           format:NULL
                                 errorDescription:nil];
```

And this inserts a null at 0 index of mutArrayOfDict.
Please help!!

Comment: I think you need to study serialization, before applying this.

Answer (score 0):

soo if I get you right you want to populate a sqlite table from a nsmutablearray so why not do this ?

[How to add nsmutable array into sqlite database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563996/how-to-add-nsmutable-array-into-sqlite-database-table)

```
for (int i = 0; i < [mutArray count]; i++)
    {
       NSString *string = [mutArray objectAtIndex:i];
       // insert query
       insert into table_name ('string') values(column_name);
    }
```

//iUser

Comment: Thank you Mingebag. Infact I want to save the complete mutable array in a single cell of the database, not to populate the columns of the database with the items of the array. I referred answer by Divz at "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355079/how-to-retrive-and-store-nsarray-from-sqlite-db-in-ios"

Comment: @Krish oh i see np so you you have your answer ?

Comment: Not exactly, the link i followed talks about NSArray. What i need is for NSMutable array. I know this shouldn't be a issue. But my code crashes at the line in my question above.

Comment: @Krish could you not do just something like that NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];

Comment: Just tried your suggestion. Same exception at same line.